# Android, how to update pariticular imageview in listview on item click

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-viewholder

I have a ViewHolder in arrayadapter class ,I want to bind click action on particular item in listview and need to update content of the item on favoriteicon click.

I have bind click action in getView method:

```
 class ViewHolder
    {

       public ImageView favoriteicon;
        public TextView title;
        public  TextView time;
        public  TextView type;
        public TextView hidden_value_id;
        public  TextView hidden_image_name;
        public boolean imageset=false;
        public  ImageView imgView;
public ViewHolder(View base)
        {
            this.favoriteicon=(ImageView) base.findViewById(R.id.favoriteicon);
            this.title = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.time = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.time);
            this.type = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.type);
            this.imgView = (ImageView) base.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            this.hidden_value_id = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.hidden_value_id);
            this.hidden_image_name = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.hidden_image_name);


        }

}


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position,View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        View rowView=view;

if(rowView==null) {


LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_listview_items, parent, false);
holder = new ViewHolder(rowView);


 rowView.setTag(holder);
}
        else {

holder=(ViewHolder)rowView.getTag();

 }


        holder.title.setText(title.get(position));
        holder.time.setText(time.get(position));
        holder.type.setText(type.get(position));
        holder.hidden_value_id.setText(id.get(position));

holder.hidden_image_name.setText(hidden_image_name.get(position));
if(holder.imageset==true)
{

 holder.favoriteicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.h);

}


        holder.favoriteicon.setOnClickListener(new 
 View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View b) {

holder.favoriteicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.h);
holder.imageset=true;


                 notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });




        return rowView;

    }
```

How to update particular item in listview on item click,if I have position of the item.

Comment: do you call notifyDataSetChanged ?

Comment: yes.. but no success

Answer (score 0):

So at the moment i imagine you have an if else statement that checks to see if the item at the current position is favourited? Now what happening is that you are setting the icons image when it is clicked however you are not changing the objects value. So when you scroll up and down and the list item is recycled it will reset the value.

You need to have something like this

```
holder.favoriteicon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View b) {
           object.setFavourited(true); 
           holder.favoriteicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.h); 
        } 
    });
```

Now this is just a guess based on the code you have posted so far. If you update the question with the rest of your adapter code i can update my answer.